# Passing ID to CGridView

Tags: yii

How to pass grid row id from CGridView to filter values in another CGridView opened in Dialog

[image]

My View Code for Form Grid(see screenshot),

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'document-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

    'columns'=>array(           
    array(
                         'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                         'template' => '{edit}{DocumentDelete}',
                         'buttons' => array(
                            'DocumentDelete' => array(
                            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/delete.png',
                             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("baseContact/DocumentDelete", array("id"=>$data->crm_document_id))',

                            ),
                             'edit' => array(
                            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png',
                             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("baseContact/edit", array("id"=>$data->crm_document_id))',

                            ),
                     ),),
       'crm_document_id',
        'name',
        'doc_type',
        'delivery_method',
        'content_subject',
        'content_body',
        'is_active',

    ),

)); ?>
```

View Code for Popup Grid,

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'ManagedocumentAttach-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>DocumentAttachmentModel::model()->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'=>'',            
        'value'=>'CHtml::checkBox("cid[]",null,array("value"=>$data->crm_document_attachment_id,"id"=>"cid_".$data->crm_document_attachment_id))',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>5),
        //'visible'=>false,
        ),      
       'crm_document_id',
        'name',
        'type',

    ),

)); ?>
```

how to pass Form edited row id to Popup GridView ?

Comment: Please add the code of your CGridView implementation.

Comment: @user714965 Added the Cgridview implementation code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you use AJAX to get the popup so i would first would make sure the ID of the edit button is the same as the ID from the item you want to open. Then you can do the following JS (using JQUERY)

```
$(".edit").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "controller/action/"+id;
        success: function(data) {
             //open dialog box and fill it with data
        }
});
```

You could also add the id as data so you can get it with `$_POST` instead of it being a variable defined by the function. If you write the JS in a php document you can use `$this->createUrl`, but that is just whatever you prefer.

If with this you can not solve your problem then let us see how you implemented it right now.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure ... but i have a technique to do it....
if i have to do something like this ....

i will give class by htmlOptions and after that i will get value which should be an id to open popup..

**example**

```
  <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
           'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ,
           'type' => TbHtml::GRID_TYPE_BORDERED,
           'template' => "{items}",
           'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'vendor_configuration_id',
                    'header' => $dataProvider->model->getAttributelabel('vendor_configuration_id'),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'idClass'),

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'menu_type',
                    'header' => $dataProvider->model->getAttributelabel('menu_type'),
                    'htmlOptions' => array(),
                ),

?>
```

now jquery for it

```
$('.idClass').on("click",function(){

var neededId = $(this).html();

 alert(neededId );
```

//openn popup based on this id or caal ajax to retrive data based on this

```
});
```